# PHP 5.5.16 Can't Enable OpenSSL

Tags: php, openssl

I'm running PHP 5.5.16 on IIS8, Windows 2012 R2 and just upgraded from 5.4.17. I am having an issue enabling the php_openssl.dll

In the ini file (yes, I've verified it's the correct ini file) I have set extension=php_openssl.dll as such, restarted IIS and phpinfo() still states [OpenSSL support  disabled (install ext/openssl)]

Also, when I map the event handler back to PHP 5.4.17, the openssl appears as desired.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Digital

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, the extension_dir = "ext" was not enabled... I changed it to:
;On windows:
extension_dir = "ext"

Comment: This is not fix the problem for me, same symptoms.  c:\php\php.ini loaded, working and confirmed.  extension_dir = "ext" uncommented.  No luck.