# Not able to enable openssl in PHP 5.6.22

Tags: php, installation, openssl, php-openssl

I was running  my application on XAMPP and  PHP 5.4.19, as I tried upgrading to PHP 5.6.22,  I am not able to enable the openssl.

Downloaded  Thread Safe  binary  from here :  http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.6.22-Win32-VC11-x86.zip

I was able to upgrade my PHP Version  except the openssl  with which  openssl_encrypt()  says  undefined function.

I double checked  php.ini  for uncommenting the  extension=php_openssl.dll  but still  no luck.

also checked with other extensions  by commenting them,  they are working as expected.

In phpinfo  I can see   OpenSSL   disabled ( install ext/openssl)  message all the time.

I made sure  the  require dll are right in place.  But  still no luck.

Comment: Did you check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25796328/4879022)?

Comment: Checked,  the extension directory was pointing to the "ext" itself.